# Silverstripe v4 MVC Directories?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm Wondering Why There is no "Models / Views / Controllers" Directories Inside SS4 Main Directory? It's Seems Like Everything Should Go Inside "mysite/code" .. How To Accomplish MVC Style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC is more of a software-architectural pattern, not how you organize files. There are only a few assumptions the SilverStripe framework makes on how you should organize your code:

#### Model

With SilverStripe 4, the default code folder for every module is named `src` or `code`. In that folder you're free to organize your files as you see fit. Ideally you build your folder structure in a [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compliant way, so that your folder-names match with your namespaces.

#### Controllers

Same as with Model classes, you can put your controllers anywhere you want.

There's a default assumption for `Page` classes though. These expect that the matching controller has the same namespace as the page. So if your page is named: `Company\Module\Pages\MyPage`, the framework would look for `Company\Module\Pages\MyPageController`.

You're free to override that though, by implementing the `getControllerName` method on your Page and return the FQCN for the controller to use.

#### Views

Also known as "templates" should be in a `templates` folder. Each module (your `mysite` folder is also a module) can have a `templates` folder.

In addition to this, you can have themes. Themes usually bundle templates, css and other assets. In the `themes` folder you can have multiple theme folders, each one can have a `templates` folder.

Comment: Thanks alot for helping 